# Counting contigious subsequences in an array with given pair of indices

Tags: algorithm, subsequence

Given an array of length n, for every index i have a integer xi (xi<=i). I need to count all continous subsequences that include these two indices also there should be no repetition for eg. 
I have counted the subsequence [1,4] for say (i=4 && x4=0), then if for next (i=5 && x5=1) I should not include the same continous sequence twice. I need to find count of all those subsequences. I tried brute force approach which wasn't sufficient to beat the time.

Can I have any better approach? Possibly O(NLOGN) or less than that?

Comment: Can you please clarify as to what exactly is the input and what you need to do with it?

Comment: No idea what you mean by this question. pls clarify

Comment: I mean for every index i ,I have a corresponding index x[i](0<=x[i]<=i),I need to count the number of distinct  continious segments which should include both these indices for eg . i have a array a[]={1,2,3,4,5} and the x[]={0,0,2,1,2} now for i=0 , i should count the segments {1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4}.{1,2,3},{1,2},{1} a total of 5. for i=1 ,there a no segments which include index(0 and 1)x[i] and i ,which are not counted before total=5+0=5,and so on i need total for all indices .hope this makes it clear.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I still have no idea what you're talking about. why when `i=0` should I count 5 segments, but for `i=1` there are none?

Comment: for i=0,i should include both x[0]=0 and 0 (the same ) index in my subarrays that means i count all subarrays which include index 0, when we come to i=1 we should include i=1 and x[1]=0 (indices 0 and 1) that means include index 0 and 1 and count the subarrays but all that subrrays are already counted so here i have no additions

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a link to it?

Comment: @oflocon Hope this helps, feel free for any queries.

Comment: @anchor this is not the original question but after gaining some insight into it the question reduced to this .

Comment: @oflocon I do not understand, your comment contradicts your question.

Comment: yes ,i was taking about time comlexity

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty simple and straightforward.

Say we are doing this for **index i.**

We generate the subsequences by extending our subsequence outside the limits(indices) **x[i]** and **i** because the subsequence will always take elements of array from **x[i] to i** and if we only expand, our subsequnce will always have the indices **x[i]** and **i**.

But of course, we will also cover the obvious subsequence from **x[i]** to **i** which is the very first subsequence.

**EDIT**:To avoid duplicates, **we must check whether the given combination of left and right boundaries have been tried or not**.

For this we will make an **adjacency list** which will contain

N linked lists.

and all linked lists are initially empty.

**Now a given subsequence with corresponding left and right boundaries have not been tried before if and only if**

```
linked list arr[left] does not contain element right.
```

**If linked list arr[left] contains element right then it means the subsequence has been printed before.**

First we fix left boundary of our subsequence to be x[i] and then with new left boundary we try all possible new right boundaries which are:

```
i,i+1,i+2 ....... N-1 , N is equal to length of array a.

Corresponding subsequenes being
if(a[j] linked list does not contain i)
 {
   print the subsequence a[j],a[j+1],......a[i]
   add i to arr[j]
 }
if(a[j] linked list does not contain i+1)
 {
   print the subsequence a[j],a[j+1],.........a[i+1]
   add i+1 to a[j]
 }

and similar if condition before all subsequences given below.      

a[j],a[j+1],...............a[i+2]
. 
.
a[j],a[j+1]..........................a[N-1]

j is x[i] for the above subsequences.
```

Then we fix left boundary to be x[i]-1 and then with new left boundary we try all possible new right boundaries which are:

```
i,i+1,i+2 ....... N-1
```

Corresponding subsequenes being

```
similar if condition as given above before all subsequences given below.      
and they will be printed if and only if the condition is true.

a[j],a[j+1],.........a[i]
a[j],a[j+1],...............a[i+1]
. 
.
a[j],a[j+1]..........................a[N-1]

j is x[i]-1 for the above subsequences.
```

**We do this till j becomes 0 and that will be the last iteration.**

Now coming to the efficiency of this algorithm, because at every step I am generating a new subsequence,and none of the steps go wasted in producing a subsequence that does not include both indices so I think it is pretty much efficient.

Comment: unfortunately,this will not do the work.say for pair(i,x[i]) =(1 ,4) and (j,x[j])=(2,3)  i think that the above algorithm will get wrong solution,won't it include some repetitions ,but i dont want to count a sequence twice .

Comment: @oflocon But you said that xi<=i and 4 is not <=1 and same applies to 2,3.

Comment: @oflocon Kindly clarify.

Comment: oh sorry ,i meant (x[i],i)=(1,4) and (x[j],j)=(2,3) in this case when you count the sequences for i=3 by your method and then go to i=4 ,it will already have  some of it before .

Comment: There will be no duplicates my friend, even when u take the pair (1,4),  the output will be exactly two subsequences (2,3,4,5) and (1,2,3,4,5).

Comment: I don't see any duplicates here.

Comment: thank you for ur help  but i am afraid that that i can't mark every start nd end in case N=10^5 ,2d array that large is not possible

Comment: @oflocon ok, do you want a solution that minimizes space? It can be achieved.

Comment: since your solution needs marking pairs,if you can somehow mark then without using an array of 10^5*10^5 it would be awesome

Comment: @oflocon using adjacency list instead of adjacency matrix greatly reduces the space required.

Comment: the complexity of above in O(n^2)?

Comment: @oflocon are you talking about time complexity?